# Update and insert from qtableWidget into MYSQL database more efficiently

Tags: mysql, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm building a desktop app with PyQt5 to connect with, load data from, insert data into and update a MySQL database. What I came up with to update the database and insert data into the database works. But I feel there should be a much faster way to do it in terms of computation speed. If anyone could help that would be really helpful. What I have as of now for updating the database is this -

```
def log_change(self, item):
        self.changed_items.append([item.row(),item.column()])
        
        # I connect this function to the item changed signal to log any cells which have been changed 


def update_db(self):
        
        # Creating an empty list to remove the duplicated cells from the initial list
        
        self.changed_items_load= []
        [self.changed_items_load.append(x) for x in self.changed_items if x not in self.changed_items_load]
        
        # loop through the changed_items list and remove cells with no values in them
        
        for db_wa in self.changed_items_load:
            if self.tableWidget.item(db_wa[0],db_wa[1]).text() == "":
                self.changed_items_load.remove(db_wa)
        
        try:
            
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            
            # loop through the list and update the database cell by cell
            
            for ecr in self.changed_items_load:
                    
                    command = ("update table1 set `{col_name}` = %s where id=%s;")
                    
                    # table widget column name matches db table column name
                    
                    data = (str(self.tableWidget.item(ecr[0],ecr[1]).text()),int(self.tableWidget.item(ecr[0],0).text()))
                    
                    mycursor.execute(command.format(col_name = self.col_names[ecr[1]]),data)
                
                    # self.col_names is a list of the tableWidget columns 
                    
            mydb.commit()        
            mycursor.close()
            
        except OperationalError:
            Msgbox = QMessageBox()
            Msgbox.setText("Error! Connection to database lost!")
            Msgbox.exec()
        
        except NameError:
            Msgbox = QMessageBox()
            Msgbox.setText("Error! Connect to database!")
            Msgbox.exec()
```

For inserting data and new rows into the db I was able to find some info online about that. But I have been unable to insert multiple lines at once as well as insert varying column length for each row. Like if I want to insert only 2 columns at row 1, and then 3 columns at row 2... something like that.

```
def insert_db(self):
        
        # creating a list of each column
        
        self.a = [self.tableWidget.item(row,1).text() for row in range (self.tableWidget.rowCount()) if self.tableWidget.item(row,1) != None]
        self.b = [self.tableWidget.item(row,2).text() for row in range (self.tableWidget.rowCount()) if self.tableWidget.item(row,2) != None]
        self.c =  [self.tableWidget.item(row,3).text() for row in range (self.tableWidget.rowCount()) if self.tableWidget.item(row,3) != None]
        self.d =  [self.tableWidget.item(row,4).text() for row in range (self.tableWidget.rowCount()) if self.tableWidget.item(row,4) != None]
        
        
        try:
            
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            
            mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO table1(Name, Date, Quantity, Comments) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" %(''.join(self.a),
                                                                ''.join(self.b),
                                                                ''.join(self.c),
                                                                ''.join(self.d)))
                
                
                    
            mydb.commit()        
            mycursor.close()
            
        except OperationalError:
            Msgbox = QMessageBox()
            Msgbox.setText("Error! Connection to database lost!")
            Msgbox.exec()
        
        except NameError:
            Msgbox = QMessageBox()
            Msgbox.setText("Error! Connect to database!")
            Msgbox.exec()
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can commit only every xxx rows. For example remove the commit from the loop, add a counter to the loop and commit only every 500 queries and of course after the loop has finished. Queries are not time expensive but transactions are. So if you do less transactions your speed will increase significantly

Comment: The commit statement isn't in the loop.

Comment: Multiple queries are possible, but the syntax depends on the sql engine you're using. To update an existing record, use the `UPDATE` statement. That said, consider using the QtSql module and set a [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html) on a [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Like if I want to insert only 2 columns at row 1, and then 3 columns at row 2

No.  A given Database table has a specific number of columns.  That is an integral part of the definition of a "table".

`INSERT` adds new rows to a table.  It is possible to construct a single SQL statement that inserts multiple rows "all at once".

`UPDATE` modifies one or more rows of a table.  The rows are indicated by some condition specified in the Update statement.

Constructing SQL with `%s` is risky -- it gets in trouble if there are quotes in the string being inserted.

(I hope these comments help you get to the next stage of understanding databases.)